# make function return something specific in a pre-set while-loop: How to approach an assignment

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop, return

In the following code I am trying to figure out what to put into a list L for f(L) to return 3.
The logic of it makes me a bit confused.

Can someone help me out in how to approach this? I am thinking that it has to be a negative number as the code will only add 1 to 0 (cnt) when n (length of integer) is smaller than 0.

```
L = []

def f(L):
    """Function to return 3"""
    n = len(L)
    i = 0
    cnt = 0

    while i < n:
        if L[i] < 0:
            cnt = cnt + 1
            i = i + 1
    return cnt
```

Comment: "it has to be a negative number" - right. _How many_ negative numbers?

Comment: Well, when I call the function with f(L) nothing comes up in my terminal no matter how many or few negative numbers I put into the list...

Comment: can't reproduce: for instance, `f([-5]) == 1`

Comment: I tried the following:

L = [-3, -1, -4]

print(f(L))


___

It returns 3. But it seems too simple. Would it be a sufficient solution? Maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: I think this is exactly right. In fact, any list of three negative numbers (so, the list should contain _exactly_ three numbers, and _all_ of them should be negative) will suffice.